# Line with size=0 still drawn by geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

So I have a `data.frame` of the activity of certain species through time. Here's part of it:

```
df <- structure(list(soort_wet = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
        2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
        2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
        2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Callophrys rubi", 
            "Coenagrion hastulatum"), class = "factor"), periode = structure(c(1L, 
                            1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
                            9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
                            16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 
                            22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L), .Label = c("1-mrt", "10-mrt", 
                  "20-mrt", "1-apr", "10-apr", "20-apr", "1-mei", "10-mei", "20-mei", 
                  "1-jun", "10-jun", "20-jun", "1-jul", "10-jul", "20-jul", "1-aug", 
                  "10-aug", "20-aug", "1-sep", "10-sep", "20-sep", "1-okt", "10-okt", 
                  "20-okt", "30-okt"), class = "factor"), activiteit = c(NA, NA, 
                    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                    3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                   NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("soort_wet", 
                   "periode", "activiteit"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(9L, 
                           15L, 70L, 76L, 131L, 137L, 192L, 198L, 253L, 259L, 314L, 320L, 
                           375L, 381L, 436L, 442L, 497L, 503L, 558L, 564L, 619L, 625L, 680L, 
                           686L, 741L, 747L, 802L, 808L, 863L, 869L, 924L, 930L, 985L, 991L, 
                           1046L, 1052L, 1107L, 1113L, 1168L, 1174L, 1229L, 1235L, 1290L, 
                           1296L, 1351L, 1357L, 1412L, 1418L, 1473L, 1479L))
```

As you can see, I have classified the activity in 4 classes (0 to 3). Now I want to draw a graph showing the activity as a line. I am using ggplot2 for this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# First attempt: size = 0 is still plotted as a line
ggplot(df, aes(x=periode,y=soort_wet, group=soort_wet)) +
  geom_line(aes(size=activiteit))
```

[image]

Well, that's almost what I want, except: I want the lines with acitiviteit==0 and hence size==0 NOT drawn. **So my first question is why are lines with size==0 drawn and how can I solve this?**
  Note that I don't want to replace the 0s with NAs, because that would cause my lines to end prematurely.

I thought I could solve this myself, by making these lines white (or colour=NA):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=periode,y=soort_wet, group=soort_wet)) +
  geom_line(aes(size=activiteit,colour=ifelse(activiteit==0,NA,"black")))
```

But that got me into deeper trouble. Does anyone understand why this doesn't work (bonus question!).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly, this is a bit annoying to do. Let me go over some of the stuff in your attempts and why it didn't work first.

First, simply stating `size=activiteit` does not mean a value of 0 will result in a size of 0. `ggplot` makes a scale first, by default between size 1 and 6. If you want to map to actual values you have to use `scale_size_identity()` or adjust the `range` in the `scale_size_continuous`. Unfortunately, adjusting this will result in a better graph, but for a reason I don't understand either, the line is still visible.

Next, your second attempt doesn't work either, since you are now mapping the value `'black'` (this sort of approach would work in base R).

Now, to get around all this, we can make a new variable that is `TRUE` when `activiteit == 0`, and map that variable to `alpha`, so we make that part of the line see-through.

Example code:

```
df$alp <- ifelse(df$activiteit == 0, T, F)

ggplot(df, aes(x=periode,y=soort_wet, group=soort_wet, alpha=alp)) +
  geom_line(aes(size=activiteit)) + theme_bw() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 0, "FALSE" = 1), guide = 'none') +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0, 15)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

Results in:

[image]

## Edit:

I just realized there is an even easier way, you can just adjust the limits of the size scale to not include 0:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=periode,y=soort_wet, group=soort_wet)) +
  geom_line(aes(size=activiteit)) + theme_bw() +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 15), limit = c(1, 3)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the resulting graphs are different, not sure why exactly. I think you are looking for the first one.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for (the first one)! I should have thought of using `alpha` myself. I think your second attempt (edit) seems to have the same issue as MLavoie did below: the last line disappears due to lack of a point to connect it to. Not sure why though.

Comment: I agree, just confirm manually that the first one is exactly what you want, and then it should do fine. Veel success!

Answer (score 0):

would that work for you?

you subset first for you want

```
df_s <- df %>% filter(activiteit > 0)
```

and then plot

```
ggplot(df_s, aes(x=periode,y=soort_wet, group=soort_wet)) +
  geom_line(aes(size=as.factor(activiteit)))
```

you size 0 is not plot.

[image]

Comment: Subsetting won't work, because of the same reason as replacing 0s with Nas won't work: it removes the last line with size = 1. BTW: I got a  `Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: it's working for me! maybe you have other librairies loaded try df_s <- df %>% dplyr::filter(activiteit > 0)

Comment: I don't understand why subsetting wont work. But it's worth noting that when you mapped size to "activiteit", there's no reason for R to think that activiteit==0 means that size ==0. That is simply a level of that variable, so it's the same as if the categories started at 25. It will simply map the lowest level to a small line, and map the highest level to a larger line. If you added `+scale_size_identity()`, then it would properly map the sizes, *except* for 0. Declaring line size 0 doesn't remove the line for some reason.

Comment: @Matt74 Compare the subsetted graph with my question. You will see that the last line with size=1 is also dropped. I have tried 'scale_size_identity' but 0 lines are still drawn. Any idea why?

Comment: @RHA, I just added a graphic and I also modified slightly the code. I still don't understand what is wrong with my approach.

Comment: What is wrong is that your graphs end at 1-jul (Coenagrion) and 1-aug (Callophrys). They should end at 10-jul and 10-aug, were the 1-line ends in the graph in the question (x-axis is difficult to read I admit). That happens because you have deleted the point at 10-jul / 10-aug. So subsetting, deleting or replacing points with NA is not an option and is not my question. I am looking to draw a line of 0 width or a transparent/white line.

Comment: Seems like your problem is not with the subsetting per se - it's with the default plotting function truncating your data, since there's no longer any reason for the x axis to extend all the way to the dates where there's no data. I'd suggest converting df$periode to a POSIXct type and exploring scale_x_datetime(). Or some other way of controlling the x axis so that you control its limits. As a side note, since your variable 'periode' is a factor (not a date) and arranged alphabetically, you'll probably run into some issues such as mrt-10 placed before mrt-2.

Comment: @Matt74 The question isn't if subsetting is my problem, but if it is the solution for my problem. And it isn't because it will do exactly the same as replacing it with NAs. `periode` is indeed a factor, not a Date or POSIXct. That is on purpose, because firstly it doesn't represent a date but an approximate ten-day-period and secondly it is easier to control spacing and labels etc if it isn't. Fortunately Axeman found a solution (using `alpha`).